# Javascript function after Http post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to create the trigger when POST isset, but from different file.

file1.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['feed_me'])): 
    echo '<script>alert("TEST !!!");</script>';
endif;
?>

<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="file2.php"></iframe>
```

file2.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['feed_me'])):

    $url = 'file1.php';
    $fields = array(
        'feed_me' => 1
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {$fields_string .= $key .'='.$value.'&';}
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    $feed_post = curlPOST($url, $fields, $fields_string);
    //var_dump($feed_post);

endif;
?>

<form method="post" action="">
  <button type="submit" name="feed_me">Feed Me !!!</button>
</form>
```

as code above, when I click submit on file2.php the response javascript alert should appear in file1.php (which has iframe to file2.php)

Could you help me solve this problem?

Comment: I have absolutley no idea what you're trying to do..

Comment: actually, i want to call javascript in one file,
but the javascript called after submit POST from another file

POST from file2, alert javascript in file1

Answer (score 0):

I think, `Iframe` will not work for `parent window`

Replace the line

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="file2.php"></iframe>
```

by

```
include_once("file2.php");
```

Above will work for you.

Comment: i see, but i need it in different files